# Python divide and conquer recursive search

Tags: python, recursion, search

My task is pretty basic but still I don't really have an idea on how to do it.
I receive a list and and now I have to check whether there is a 0 in that list.
Basically my function would be:

```
search(L,0,len(L)-1)
```

How would I now split the list into smaller pieces and find out if there is a 0 in that list

Only conditions are:

- recursively
- with some form of divide and conquer

edit: is that going to be ok?

```
# Name, Vorname:
# Matr.-Nr:


def teile_herrsche(L,startIndex,endIndex):
    if len(L) > 0:
        if L[endIndex] == 0:
            return True
        elif endIndex > -1:
            return teile_herrsche(L,startIndex,endIndex-1)
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


L=[1,2,3,4]
print(teile_herrsche(L,0,len(L)-1))
```

Comment: Checking each element with a simple for loop scales linearly. What is the point of making the code more complex with a divide-and-conquer approach?

Answer (score 0):

I dislike the comment of questioning the question. First of all it's obviously a school exercise with given conditions and second it isn't answering the question at all. True is, that the exercise is an example of how not to teach the benefits of recursion. As for answering if there is a 0 in an unordered list, each element has to be checked in the worst case.

Now the problem with the given attempt is, that it doesn't divide at all. You are just making a linear search in reverse order by just reducing the least index by one.
The principle of DAC is to split the haystack into two (almost) equally large haystacks and than doing this with these haystacks again until we have only 1 element left (which cannot be divided further). This is than checked to the condition and the result returned. Lookup a binary tree, starting from the root until reaching the leaves, each node in between being only a part of the former list.

A possible solution would be for example to do it like this

```
#recursive DAC testing for needle
def findrec(haystack, needle=0):
    #print(haystack)
    return (len(haystack) == 1 and haystack[0] == needle) or \
        (len(haystack) > 1 and (findrec(haystack[:len(haystack)//2]) or \
        findrec(haystack[len(haystack)//2:]))) or False
    
    
L=[5,2,0,5,1,4,5,4,6]
findrec(L)
```

res:

```
[5, 2, 0, 5, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6]
[5, 2, 0, 5]
[5, 2]
[5]
[2]
[0, 5]
[0]

True
```

(To see, how the list is divided, uncomment the inner print)

For explanation the first statement in return
`(len(haystack) == 1 and haystack[0] == needle)` resolves to True only if the haystack is exactly one element and this element is the needle

If the haystack is larger than one, we can further divide by calling the function with the parameter `[:len(haystack)//2]` => [0] to [rounded down half of the list] and `[len(haystack)//2:]` => [rounded down half of the list] to [end]

The last statement returns False otherwise.

Because all 3 statements are logically or'd, one True is enough to make all False from other elements irrelevant. As the test for needle is first evaluated, no further  subdivision is made in that branch if needle is found.

---

And here's an expanded version using `if/elif/else` -

1. If the input `t` is empty, it is not possible for the query `q` to exist in it. This is the base case, return false.
2. (inductive) `t` is *not* empty. If `t` has a single element, return true if the element matches the query, `q`
3. (inductive) `t` is *not* empty and it has more than one element. Divide the list to find the `mid`-point, and recur on the two sub-problems, `t[0:mid]` or `t[:mid]`.

This encodes easily as -

```py
def findrec (t, q):
  if len(t) == 0:
    return False        # (1)
  elif len(t) == 1:
    return t[0] == q    # (2)
  else:
    mid = len(t) // 2   # (3)
    return findrec(t[0:mid], q) or findrec(t[mid:], q)

t = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(findrec(t, 0)) # False
print(findrec(t, 3)) # True
print(findrec(t, 6)) # True
print(findrec(t, 9)) # False
```